# 64 bit & 32 bit Registry issue in Windows (Programming in c#)

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to get data from the registry of windows to my software but there is one thing i'm having trouble with it:

if my software runs on a 64 bit system the registry path will be :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\AVAST Software\Avast ProgramFolder
```

and if my software runs on 32 bit system the registry path will be :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AVAST Software\Avast  ProgramFolder
```

What can i do ? to double check every time ?

maybe i will check only the second option(without the `\Wow6432Node\`) and when the software runs on 64 bit it will automatically add to the path the `\Wow6432Node\` ?

What is the best solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do anything further, you should have a good read of the documentation of the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). It's really important that you have a clear understanding of what it does.

OK, now that you understand the registry redirector, let's look at how to tackle your problem. You have a few options. The simplest is build your program to target x86, and access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AVAST Software\Avast ProgramFolder` no matter what bitness system you run on. That way your code will always run in a 32 bit process and so always see the 32 bit view of the registry. The registry redirector will handle the mapping onto the true physical `Wow6432Node` transparently.

Alternatively, if you must use `AnyCPU`, and must cater for running inside a 64 bit process, you need to use the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration. This allows you to read from the 32 bit view of the registry, even from a 64 bit process. But again you access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\AVAST Software\Avast ProgramFolder` but ask for that key with respect to the 32 bit view of the registry.

---

The golden rule with the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx) is that you must not hard code `Wow6432Node` into your paths. The documentation says it like this:

> Redirected keys are mapped to physical locations under Wow6432Node. For example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software is redirected to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node. However, the physical location of redirected keys should be considered reserved by the system. Applications should not access a key's physical location directly, because this location may change.

Don't be tempted to break that rule. The system provides mechanisms to read from the 32 bit view in a supported manner.

Comment: Nice explaining but its still a little bit vague for me(after reading the article and your comment), there is 4 situition to consider:
1. A 64 bit program running on 64 OS.

Comment: All you need to do is call `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32)` and you are good to go in all scenarios.

Comment: Nice explaining but its still a little bit vague for me(after reading the article and your comment).
could you give me an example?

(I have a 64 OS, and all the path mention below was checked on my OS)

if i get (in my system) this path :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avira\Antivir Desktop Path
my code is : 
installPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avira\Antivir", "Desktop Path", null);

How i write this the right way?

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: so if i understand you correctly, this:
 installPath = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Avira\Antivi‌​r", "Desktop Path", null);
Becomes
RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
           rk = rk.OpenSubKey(@"\SOFTWARE\Avira\Antivi‌r");
           string installPath = rk.GetValue("Desktop Path").ToString();
?

Comment: Yup, that's the basic approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state which version of the framework you're using, but if you're using 4+ then you can use [`Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem%28VS.100%29.aspx) to determine the bitiness of the environment and therefore look/write to the correct place.

Comment: That is no help. What if you are running in a 32 bit process under WOW64.

Comment: You're still reading from and writing to a consistent place based on the system and not the app itself.

Comment: No. That's really not it at all. If you are going to hard code Wow6432Node (and you really should not), you have to take the decision based on the bitness of the process rather than the bitness of the system.

Comment: You probably _should_ but you _needn't_; at any rate, you could use [`Is64BitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess(v=vs.110).aspx) for that, then.

Comment: You really should not hard code Wow6432Node. Ever. If I understand your last comment correctly. The system provides APIs for dealing with registry views.